# jquery serializeArray() results sometimes in empty string or empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an `aspx.net` page with a large form to add an order.
This page contains a table with many order lines.
Per order line, there are 20 form fields and 5 hidden fields.

There is a print button to print the order, but before that it has to save it first.

My problem is that when I use `$("form").serializeArray()`, the array is 1 to 1.000.000 times empty.
It doesn't matter which browser I use.

This is making me crazy because lot's of users are calling me to fix this problem a.s.a.p.
I don't know to where to start debugging.

- Is `serializeArray()` the problemen?
- Or maybe the postdata is to large or corrupt?
- Maybe the `WebMethod` needs some extra attributes?

Here is my print button

```
<input type='button' title='Print' onclick='PrintOrder(true)' />
```

```
function PrintOrder(autosave) {
  if (autosave) {
    // save my order and call a callback function after it's completed
    AutoSaveForm(function () {
      PrintOrder(false);
    });
  } else {
    // show my pdf page
    window.open('printorder.pdf');
    return;
  }
}

var inAutoSaveForm = false;

// this function is needed to autosave my order
// fn is a callback function when it's successfull done.
function AutoSaveForm(fn) {
  if (!inAutoSaveForm) {
    // serializeArray to post my form by the ajax function
    var fields = $("form").serializeArray();

    // json format
    var myData = {
      'orderId': orderId,
      'fields': fields
    };

    myData = JSON.stringify(myData);

    ShowLoader();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Order.aspx/AutoSave",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      timeout: (1000 * 60 * 10),
      data: myData,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          fn.call();
        }, 25);
      },
      error: function (x, t, m) {
        alert("Error, please try again later.\n\n" + t);
      },
      complete: function (msg) {
        // .. do nothing yet
      }
    });

    inAutoSaveForm = true;
  } else {
    fn.call();
  }
}
```

Here is my .NET code to save the order.
Maybe I have to put some attributes to the WebMethod ?

```
[WebMethod]
public static string VerwerkForm(field[] fields) {
    // do the magic
    return "ok";
}

public class field {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your statement about the problem. You said "....My problem is that when I use $("form").serializeArray(), the array is 1 to 1.000.000 times empty..."...can you please re-phrase or elaborate on that?

Comment: In the webmethod I try to read the field array. I throw an exception and sent myself an e-mail when the field array is empty. The problem is that most of the time the field array is filled, so I can save my order. But sometimes the field array is empty while the formdata is not empty.

Comment: So, it sounds like you are receiving an empty array when you POST to your WebMethod sometimes. Without knowing what you are entering in your form fields, I can only assume that there may be some special characters that the serializeArray is having difficulty reading and hence produces an empty array as a result. You should examine the cases when you do get an empty array for a certain kind of input values and see if they consistently produce the problem.

Comment: Also, remember that you will need to give each of your input fields a 'name' attribute and a unique value for that attribute otherwise serializeArray will not know what key to use when creating the serializable array.

Comment: First of all, if this really happened once in a million times, you wouldn't get so many calls ;-) second, you're saying that fields is empty while form data is not ... so what's inside form data then?

Comment: I'm busy now trying to reproduce it. once in a million times is not what is happening, it happens every day once or twice and is driving us crazy because we cannot reproduce it yet. So if you have some advice, please help